# DHCP Administrators Group: No Permissions Granted on DHCP Server

Tags: active-directory, dhcp, windows-server-2012-r2

I have added 'Group1' as a member of the DHCP Administrators group in my domain. Problem is, Groups and/or Users added to that group are not given permissions to view/manage the DHCP servers. How do I implement these security settings on the DHCP Servers?

I have checked `whoami /groups` for users added through a group and directly. Both instances show that the User is a member of the DHCP Administrators group so I am pretty sure it is applying to the users. It doesn't seem that the DHCP Servers themselves are accepting the Security Settings.
[image]

My environment: Two Server2012 R2 DHCP servers configured for load balanced failover. AD Schema and Forest are both Functional Level Server2012R2.

Comment: Did you logout of the domain and back in with that user after adding it to the group?

Comment: Yes I logged out/in.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was due to an incomplete configuration on the primary DHCP Server. The server was Authorized for the domain through the MMC snapin which did not add "DHCP Administrators" as a group with local permissions.

Comment: Did you use Add-DhcpServerSecurityGroup to fix this? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dhcpserver/add-dhcpserversecuritygroup